# How add index on a jinja template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I'm passing list to my Jinja template through my Python code.

```py
list = [123,232,334,412]
```

How can I add an indexing to the output ?

For example:

```
some text id1 = 123, id2 = 232, id3 = 334, id5 = 412
```

What I tried was:

```
some text {{ list | join(', id = ' ) }}
```

But the output contains no indexes:

```
some text id = 123, id = 232, id = 334, id = 412
```

Comment: Your code does not produce what you claim it does; `some text {{ list | join(', id = ' ) }}`, gives `some text 123, id = 232, id = 334, id = 412`, so there is no `id = ` in front of the first value. This said, that won't be possible without a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use loop.index to get this.

```
from jinja2 import Template
s = "{% for element in elements %}id{{loop.index}} element {% endfor %}"

template = Template(s)
idx = template.render(elements=[123,232,334,412])

print(idx)
```

output

```
id1 element id2 element id3 element id4 element
```